# Where is the clipboard data stored in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, copy-paste

In bash, I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> it "cuts" text behind my cursor.

Then when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> it pastes the text back.

Is there a file where the cut text is stored?

Comment: couldn't it be in memory?

Comment: yea, I was just hoping there was a file it saved to so I could access it with another program.

Comment: Bash doesn't save the text between restarts, so there is no reason to store it in file at all.

Comment: If you want to manipulate clipboard take a look at [xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/).

Comment: @jimmij, the X clipboard is separate from the kill ring, which is what ctrl+u and ctrl+y manipulate (and what is referred to by this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "clipboard" -- actually called the *kill ring* -- is implemented by the `readline` library. It is not persistent, so it is not saved in a file.

There are lots of keystroke commands for "kill"ing and "yank"ing text, which are described in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Killing-Commands):

> Killing text means to delete the text from the line, but to save it away for later use, usually by yanking (re-inserting) it back into the line. (‘Cut’ and ‘paste’ are more recent jargon for ‘kill’ and ‘yank’.)

More complete documentation is in [this section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Killing).

Answer (score 1):

`xsel` can copy and paste to three different "clipboards". By default, it uses the X Window System primary selection, which is basically whatever is currently in selection. The X Window System also has a secondary selection (which isn't used much), and a clipboard selection. You're probably looking for the clipboard selection, since that's what the desktop environment (e.g. Gnome, KDE, XFCE) uses for its clipboard. To use that with xsel:

```
xsel --clipboard < new-clipboard-contents.txt
xsel --clipboard > current-clipboard-contents.txt
```

or use this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/XmClipboardStartCopy.3.html)